# Setting TCP flags with IO::Socket::Async

Tags: tcp, network-programming, telnet, raku

I'm writing a Telnet library, and one of the commands requires setting the URGENT flag on the TCP packet sent according to [RFC854](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854):

> The Synch is sent via the TCP send operation with the Urgent
> flag set and the DM as the last (or only) data octet.

How can I do this?

Comment: This isn't supported at the present. You could look to see if it has been reported, and if not report it yourself.

Comment: @Close-voter How exactly is setting one bit in a `send()` flag 'too broad'?

Comment: IO::Socket::INET supports getting file descriptors now, and IO::Socket::Async is being worked on. It'd be possible to use NativeCall to do this once more people use the versions of Rakudo that have it